# When is the TemplateHaskell extension required in libraries providing TH deriving functions?

Tags: haskell, cabal, template-haskell

I was under the impression that using functions of type `:: Name -> Q [Dec]` had to be wrapped in a splice with the `TemplateHaskell` extension turned on, as e.g. documented in [`aeson`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.6.2.1/docs/Data-Aeson-TH.html):

```
$(deriveJSON defaultOptions ''(,,,))
```

But I just noticed the [`lens` docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-3.10.0.1/docs/Control-Lens.html) show using these TH functions without a splice (or `TemplateHaskell`), and I just tried it in a library I'm working on and it seems to work fine, even with something like this at the top level:

```
fmap concat $ forM [''X , ''Y , ''Z ] deriveFoo
```

Yet after making those modifications (removing from splice and removing pragma), I'm getting [this error](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/8443), unless I put a `extensions: TemplateHaskell` line in the test-suite block, which I don't really understand.

So is the splice thing a myth? And if so, then why do I need `TemplateHaskell` in an extensions list for the test-suite?

Comment: Are you confusing the ' and '' suffixes in the Lens docs for ' and '' prefixes used in templatehaskell?  The former is template haskell syntax to refer to the name objects of the variable.  The latter is just a valid character for a variable name (ie- x', or "x prime" is just a new variable distinct from x).  I have used template haskell in lens, but always with a splice (I certainly don't know every nook and crany though, so I might be missing something).

Comment: @jamshidh no, see the example of `makeLenses` usage at the very top of the lens docs I linked to

Comment: The `$(..)` syntax is optional for top-level splices. It's still Template Haskell (even if the lens docs do not explicitly state this), so you need to enable the extension one way or another.

Comment: @raymonad that makes sense, I guess the vagaries of cabal were misleading me there. If you want to make that an answer (and even better: link to the docs), I'll accept it.

Comment: I really wish the splice syntax hadn't been made optional at the top level. It only confuses people without making anything easier.